# ASP.NET Adding ContentPlaceHolder to MasterPage

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I'm building a kind of simple In-Application CMS and I'm gonno let the user to upload an HTML and a CMS file as Masterpage.

A solution I thought was asking user to put some Pre-Defined Tags inside HTML so I can replace them with ContentPlaceHolder control. The reason of replacing ContentPlaceHolder is that I may have some Web Controls and need postback handling so I cannot convert everything to Html and put them to an HTML and push to client.

And the Questions:

1- Is there any better solution?
2- Is it possible? How can I replace some string with CPH Control?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you cannot dynamically generate content placeholders at runtime.  So your actual masterpage will have to have them in place ahead of time.

I think you may be able to achieve what you are after by putting Literal controls before and after each content placeholder.  Then you could parse your CMS html to determine which html comes before a placeholder and which comes after.  Finally set each Literal's text property to the respective parsed html.